# Groupby and create a new column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like this,

```
+----------+--------+
|id_       | p      |
+----------+--------+
|  1       | A      |
|  1       | B      |
|  1       | B      |
|  1       | A      |
|  1       | A      |
|  1       | B      |
|  2       | C      |
|  2       | C      |
|  2       | C      |
|  2       | A      |
|  2       | A      |
|  2       | C      |
---------------------
```

I want to create another column for each group of `id_`. Column is made using pandas now with the code,

```
sample.groupby(by=['id_'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda grp : grp['p'].ne(grp['p'].shift()).cumsum())
```

How can I do this in pyspark dataframe.?

Currently I am doing this with a help of a pandas UDF, which runs very slow.

What are the alternatives.?

Expected column will be like this,

```
1
2
2
3
3
4
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

Comment: did you try pyspark.sql.udf : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/udf.html ?

Comment: I was not able to use it to get required result. I was not able to compare the lag and current values. Maybe I am missing out something

Comment: can you share expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combination of udf and window functions to achieve your results:

```
# required imports
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

# define a window, which we will use to calculate lag values
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(F.col('id_'))

# define user defined function (udf) to perform calculation on each row
def f(lag_val, current_val):
    if lag_val != current_val:
       return 1
    return 0
# register udf so we can use with our dataframe
func_udf = F.udf(f, IntegerType())

# read csv file
df = spark.read.csv('/path/to/file.csv', header=True)

# create new column with lag on window we created earlier, apply udf on lagged
# and current value and then apply window function again to calculate cumsum
df.withColumn("new_column", func_udf(F.lag("p").over(w), df['p'])).withColumn('cumsum', F.sum('new_column').over(w.partitionBy(F.col('id_')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))).show()

+---+---+----------+------+
|id_|  p|new_column|cumsum|
+---+---+----------+------+
|  1|  A|         1|     1|
|  1|  B|         1|     2|
|  1|  B|         0|     2|
|  1|  A|         1|     3|
|  1|  A|         0|     3|
|  1|  B|         1|     4|
|  2|  C|         1|     1|
|  2|  C|         0|     1|
|  2|  C|         0|     1|
|  2|  A|         1|     2|
|  2|  A|         0|     2|
|  2|  C|         1|     3|
+---+---+----------+------+

# where:
#  w.partitionBy : to partition by id_ column
#  w.rowsBetween : to specify frame boundaries
#  ref https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html#rowsBetween-long-long-
```

Comment: I almost posted the same answer, till I saw that you have already posted it.

Comment: Works as expected. Can you link me to any resources for Window functions maybe other than the docs.?

Comment: Can you suggest a solution without udf .?